# NHibernate - Saving simple parent-child relationship generates unnecessary selects with assigned id

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Entities:

```
public class Parent
{
    virtual public long Id { get; set; }
    virtual public string Description { get; set; }

    virtual public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    virtual public long Id { get; set; }
    virtual public string Description { get; set; }

    virtual public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(x => x.Description);

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .AsSet()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(x => x.Description);

        References(x => x.Parent)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

and

```
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var parent = new Parent { Id = 1 };

            parent.Children = new HashSet<Child>();

            var child1 = new Child { Id = 2, Parent = parent };
            var child2 = new Child { Id = 3, Parent = parent };

            parent.Children.Add(child1);
            parent.Children.Add(child2);

            session.Save(parent);

            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

this codes generates following sql

```
NHibernate: SELECT child_.Id, child_.Description as Descript2_0_, child_.Parent_id as Parent3_0_ FROM [Child] child_ WHERE child_.Id=@p0;@p0 = 2 [Type: Int64 (0)]
NHibernate: SELECT child_.Id, child_.Description as Descript2_0_, child_.Parent_id as Parent3_0_ FROM [Child] child_ WHERE child_.Id=@p0;@p0 = 3 [Type: Int64 (0)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Parent] (Description, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1);@p0 = NULL[Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int64 (0)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Child] (Description, Parent_id, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);@p0 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p2 = 2 [Type:Int64 (0)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO [Child] (Description, Parent_id, Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);@p0 = NULL [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = 1 [Type: Int64 (0)], @p2 = 3 [Type:Int64 (0)]
```

Why are these two selects generated and how can I remove it?

Comment: These might not be necessarily unnecessary. Besides, you didn't mention the problem it is causing? or is it just that you are wondering why?

Comment: I'm really confused with nhibernate's persistence mechanism. I've read NHibernate in Acion, reference manual and several blog posts about cascade and inverse options but it's still not clear to me. So I decided to experiment with several mappings and see how it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

The selects are there because you are explicitly setting the Ids. NHibernate doesn't know whether to inser or update so it has to find out if they exist in the database. If they do it will update, if not (as in your case) it will insert.